# Getting 'AppIdNoAuthError' in iFlyTek Spark Integration

Tags: python, apache-spark, chat, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to use Spark API from iFlytek where getting AppIdNoAuthError

**Langchain Reference**:https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/chat/sparkllm

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enabled only 3.5 chat model. So, I need to pass it to LLM

```
chat = ChatSparkLLM(
    spark_api_url="wss://spark-api.xf-yun.com/v3.5/chat",
    spark_app_id="****", spark_api_key="***", spark_api_secret="**"
)
```

Then it worked fine, Thanks